Different between Curly braces{} and brackets[] while initializing array in C#?
I am really curious to know what is the different between these lines?
//with curly braces
int[] array2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, };
//with brackets
int[] array3 = [1, 2, 3, 4,];

Console.WriteLine(array2[1]);
Console.WriteLine(array3[1]);

//the output is the same.

I want to know what is the different between using curly braces and brackets while initializing values.

I don't think the two expressions are any different for arrays, but they can be quite different when initialising other types.

@Sweeper: Even for arrays, you can use the spread operator in collection expressions, which you can't in regular array initializers.

@JonSkeet I was specifically talking about the example in the question. I was thinking about how collection initialisers are lowered differently from collection expressions. Collection expressions would try to find a "create method" in the target type, for example.

@Sweeper: I think the example in the question is unfortunate, really - it's drawing too much attention to that one case where the last part of the question it more interesting. It's like saying "what's the difference between double x = 1.5f; and double x = 1.5d; - they happen to be the same, but double x = 1.4f; and double x = 1.4d; are different. (And your comment could easily be read as "for arrays specifically, there's no difference between curly braces and square braces".)

It's easy, curly braces - { } - collection initializer - Add method, square bracers  - [ ] - collection expression - Create method.

@Sinatr: No, curly braces aren't always a collection initializer. The example in this question isn't a collection initializer, it's an array initializer. (Collection initializers only occur within the context of the new operator.)

@JonSkeet, right, it's not that easy: arrays are collections (ICollection), but are not collections, they have special alternative syntax and it has nothing to do with collection initializer =D

"I want to know what is the different between using curly braces and brackets while initializing values." Clearly, nothing, since you get the same output from both. What more do you want beyond the test you already made here?

@JonSkeet I think that's an exceedingly charitable interpretation, to the point where you're effectively answering a different question.

In the example you've given, they mean the same thing. But collection expressions are in general more flexible. In particular:

They can create instances of collections other than arrays
They can use the spread operator to include sequences

For example:
ImmutableList<int> x = [0, .. Enumerable.Range(100, 5), 200];

That creates an immutable list of integers with values 0, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 200.
Note that while collection initializers can also be used to initialize non-array collection types in a somewhat flexible way, they're more limited than collection expressions and still require the new part. So for example:
// Valid
List<int> x = new() { 1, 2, 3 };

// Not valid
List<int> x = { 1, 2, 3 };

// Not valid (collection initializers assume mutability)
ImmutableList<int> x = new() { 1, 2, 3 };

Collection expressions address both of these concerns.

It's probably also worth mentioning that collection initializers are an older feature and collection expressions are a newer feature, so one is the "old way" and one is the "new way", though both are supported.

There is actually a difference for empty arrays.
As was mentioned in this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/79254772/2893207 by @LMA the empty array in case of curly braces will create a new array instance:
int[] array1 = { };
int[] array2 = { };
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(array1, array2)); // Prints false

Collection expression for the empty array is optimized, it uses the Array.Empty<>() cached object.
int[] array1 = [];
int[] array2 = [];
int[] array3 = Array.Empty<int>();
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(array1, array2)); // Prints true
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(array1, array3)); // Prints true

